# Progressive Mp4 Streaming using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, streaming, mp4, http-streaming

I am facing problem while streaming mp4 video from any part or section using asp.net script. Script is working well when you stream mp4 video from start but failed to stream if you want to choose any starting point.

Sample script i am using

```
if (filename.EndsWith(".mp4") && filename.Length > 2)
{
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   // Sample logic to calculate approx length based on starting time.
   if (context.Request.Params["starttime"] != null && context.Request.Params["d"] != null)
   {
       double total_duration = Convert.ToDouble(context.Request.Params["d"]);
       double startduration = Convert.ToDouble(context.Request.Params["starttime"]);
       double length_sec = (double)fs.Length / total_duration; // total length per second
       seekpos = (long)(length_sec * startduration);
   }
   if (seekpos==0)
   {
       position = 0;
       length = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
   }
   else
   {
       position = Convert.ToInt32(seekpos);
       length = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length - position);
   }
   // Add HTTP header stuff: cache, content type and length        
   context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
   context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
   context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
   context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
   if (position > 0)
   {
       fs.Position = position;
   }
   // Read buffer and write stream to the response stream
   const int buffersize = 16384;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];

   int count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
   while (count > 0)
   {
      if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
      {
          context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer,0, count);
          context.Response.Flush();
          count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
      }
      else
      {
          count = -1;
      }
   }
   fs.Close();
}
```

I think problem is in the following line, if i remove it, video still can be played but from start
       if (position > 0)
       {
           fs.Position = position;
       }
There may be starting mp4 header like used in flv streaming to track seek position due to which stream can't be recognized, if seek position > 0

Can any one help me in this.

Regards.

Comment: Maybe you should consider some players (silverlight or flash), because setting the position in FileStream only works in text files. very small chance to work in an mp4.

Comment: the problem is e.g when user click on flash player like jwplayer, it will send starttime to streaming script, but streaming script can't send content from position from where it is requrested in case of mp4, it works in flash flv case. it works while implementing http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Internet-Information-Services-IIS7-Version2, but if it will be good and easy if worked directly via http script.

Answer (score 0):

You set the Content-Length to the file length but then only send part of the file.

Also I don't think you can just divide the video like that, I think you have to set the file position to the beginning of an I-frame, this would mean somehow parsing the mp4 file and finding the nearest I-frame to the time you want and set the file position to that byte then start streaming from there.